# Ajax wont call MVC controller method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX function in my javascript to call my controller method. When I run the AJAX function (on a button click) it doesn't hit my break points in my method. It all runs both the success: and error:. What do I need to change to make it actually send the value from $CSV.text to my controller method?

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// Convert JSON to CSV & Display CSV
        $CSV.text(ConvertToCSV(JSON.stringify(data)));

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditFence", "Configuration")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { value : $CSV.text() },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditFence(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteNewFenceFile(value);
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            var obj = new
            {
                success = true,
                responseText = "Zones have been saved."
            };
            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var obj = new
            {
                success = false,
                responseText = "Zone save encountered a problem."
            };
            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**RESULT**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the data you POST to your controller and the `Action` you POST to:

```
data: { value = $CSV.text() }

url: '@Url.Action("EditFence", "Configuration")'
```

The `$CSV` is possible a jquery Object related to an html element. You need to read it's text property and pass this as data, instead of the jQuery object.

Doing the above changes you would achieve to make the correct POST. However, there is another issue, regarding your Controller. You Controller does not respond to the AJAX call after doing his work but issues a redirection.

**Update**

> it would be helpful for you to tell me how the ActionResult should
>   look, in terms of a return that doesn't leave the current view but
>   rather just passes back that it was successful.

The Action to which you POST should be refactored like below. As you see we use a try/catch, in order to capture any exception. If not any exception is thrown, we assume that everything went ok. Otherwise, something wrong happened. In the happy case we return a response with a successful message, while in the bad case we return a response with a failure message.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditFence(string value)
{
    try
    {
        WriteNewFenceFile(value);
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        var obj = new 
        { 
            success = true, 
            responseText= "Zones have been saved."
        };
        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // log the Exception...

        var obj = new 
        { 
            success = false, 
            responseText= "Zone save encountered a problem."
        };
        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)); 
    }
}
```

Doing this refactor, you can utilize it in the client as below:

```
$CSV.text(ConvertToCSV(JSON.stringify(data)));

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EditFence", "Configuration")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { value = JSON.stringify($CSV.text()) },
    success: function(response){
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function(response){
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why? Can you offer an explanation for the OP so they can know why the data passing method they were using did not link up with the `value` parameter in the MVC action?

Comment: First of all he didn't post to the correct action. As it seems. I expect that by changing this it will see his Action to be hit.

Comment: I'm also assuming that `$CSV` is a DOM element, I think you made the same assumption, but it helps to explain why passing a DOM element, or even the DOM element's text as the data parameter on an ajax call will not link up with the MVC action parameters

Comment: $CSV is related to an HTML element. I miss typed on the Action I'm calling, but it would be helpful for you to tell me how the ActionResult should look, in terms of a return that doesn't leave the current view but rather just passes back that it was successful.

Comment: @MatthewCzajka Please check my update and let me know.

Comment: I get a response in an alert message but I am still not hitting the method, nor the try/catch. The error says Invalid Json primitive. When i change to "data: { 'value' : $CSV }" I get an error saying "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in the console.

Comment: ...My bad I copied and paste from your question....the client part, without making the corresponding changes. Now the client will make an ajax call, open the developer tools and check where this call goes? In Chrome developer tools open by pressing F12. You can see that I said by going to the Network tab and then POSTing your form.

Comment: Please check my update, you might need to `JSON.strignify` the data you post. As a side note, please avoid editing your question. For the readers of your question it would be difficult to get along with what is going on when they read the question and the answers. Furthermore, not changing the question you will help others in the future that will meet the exact the same problem.

Comment: I was able to get it to work this morning. Using your help I got to a solution. I created a variable index, set index equal to $CSV.text() and I then passed index as the data value.

Comment: @MatthewCzajka Great ! I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript is actually in a JS file and not a CSHTML file, then this will be emitted as a string literal:

```
@Url.Action("EditFile", "Configuration")
```

Html Helpers don't work in JS files... so you'll need to point to an actual url, like `'/configuration/editfile'`

Also, it looks like you're posting to a method called EditFile, but the name of your method in the controller code snippet is EditFence, so that will obviously be an issue too.

Comment: It isn't in a JS file, it is in script tags in a CSHTML file. And I miss typed in my question. I did mean EditFence, not EditFile.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on these lines:

```
success: alert("Zones have been saved."),
error: alert("Zone save encountered a problem.")
```

This effectively running both functions immediately and sets the return values of these functions to the success and error properties. Try using an anonymous callback function.

```
success: function() {
     alert("Zones have been saved.");
},
error: function() {
    alert("Zone save encountered a problem.")
}
```

Comment: That did help with my one problem of both of them occurring.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add `contentType` the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will work because it looks like you have a large csv string. So your code should be like this example

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Create Object
        var items = [
            { name: "Item 1", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
            { name: "Item 2", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
            { name: "Item 3", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" }
        ];

        // Convert Object to JSON
        var $CSV = $('#csv');
        $CSV.text(ConvertToCSV(JSON.stringify(items)));
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditFence", "Configuration")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {value:$CSV.text()},
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```